# Calculating User Input Percentage in C

Tags: c, percentage

For homework I have to calculate a percent discount from user input percentages in C, every time I run this program it returns the result as the original price and not with the discounted percentage(For Homework I was told to do this without the percentage operator.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double price_book;
    int percent;
    double grand_total;

    printf("What is the price of the book?\n");
            scanf("%lf", &price_book);

    printf("The Price of the book before discount is %.2lf\n\n",price_book);


    printf("How much percent discount is to be applied?\n");
            scanf("%d", &percent);

    grand_total = (100-percent)/100 * price_book;

    printf("\nThe total after discount is %.2lf\n", &grand_total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Integer division truncates. `(100-percent)/100` is always 0.

Comment: Please enable warnings when compiling. You are trying to print an address in your last `printf`; you just need `printf("%.2lf\n", grand_total);`. The argument for `scanf` is okay, though: Here you need the `&`);

Comment: Also, what you call the "percentage operator" is actually called "modulus" and its function has nothing to do with percentages.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(100-percent)/100` is an *integer* expression, all involved values are integers and so you get integer division which will result in the value `0`.

Instead use floating-point values: `(100.0-percent)/100.0`

Answer (score 1):

Along with what [Joachim Pileborg said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32732136/4228131)  you need to fix this:

```
printf("\nThe total after discount is %.2lf\n", &grand_total);
```

change it to:

```
printf("\nThe total after discount is %.2lf\n", grand_total);
```

`&` operator is used to take address. And you don't possibly need the address for `printf`, like you need for `scanf`. Roughly speaking, in `scanf()` you need the address to put the console input/user input into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could check the code below, this works and `price_book` is calculated along with `percent`, check below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double price_book;
    int percent;
    double grand_total;

    printf("What is the price of the book?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &price_book);

    printf("The Price of the book before discount is %.2lf\n\n",price_book);

    printf("How much percent discount is to be applied?\n");
    scanf("%d", &percent);

    grand_total = price_book - ( (percent)/100.0 * price_book);

    printf("\nThe total after discount is %.2lf\n", grand_total);

    return 0;
}
```